# Proof of the Crossbar theorem

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, triangles

A teacher asked me to prove the well known *Crossbar theorem*. I tried it in the following way:-

*Given:* If $D$ is in the interior of $\triangle ABC$, then prove that $\overrightarrow{AD}$ intersects $\overline{BC}$.

[Link for Diagram](http://tube.geogebra.org/material/simple/id/1819575)

*Proof:* Take $F-A-C$.

$1.$ $F$ and $C$ are on the opposite side of $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$. ($D$ is in the interior of $\triangle ABC$)

$2.$ $D$ is on $C$ side of $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$.

$3.$ $F$ and $D$ are on opposite side of $\overleftrightarrow{AB}$.

$4.$ Open ray $\overrightarrow{AD}$ belongs to $D$ side of $\overleftrightarrow {AB}$.

$5.$ $\overleftrightarrow{AD}$ doesn't intersect $\overline{FB}$ for $A \not=B$.

$6.$ $\overrightarrow{AG}$ and $\overrightarrow{AD}$ are opposite open rays. ($D-A-G$)

$7.$ $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$ separates plane of $\triangle FBC$ into two open (opposite) half-planes, one belonging to $B$ side of open ray $\overrightarrow{FB}$ and other belonging to $G$ side of open ray $\overrightarrow{AG}$.

$(A)$Open ray $\overrightarrow{AG}$ doesn't intersect $\overline {FB}$ for $A\not=F.$

$(B)$$\overline {FB}$ doesn't contain $A$ and $\overrightarrow{AG}$ doesn't contain $F.$

$8.$ Given $\overleftrightarrow{AD}=\overrightarrow{AD}+\overrightarrow{AG}$ deosn't intersect $\overline{FB}$.

$9.$ $B$ is on $F$ side of $\overleftrightarrow{AD}$.

$10.$ $C$ and $F$ are on opposite side of $\overleftrightarrow{AD}$.

$11.$ This implies that $B$ and $C$ are on opposite side of $\overleftrightarrow{AD}$.

$12.$ Hence proved that $\overleftrightarrow{AD}$ intersects $\overline{BC}$.

I was told that there is something wrong with this proof, but I can't find what... This seems fine to me. Can anyone point me out the mistake?

Comment: For such an elementary proof, I think it would be helpful if you told us what kind of facts you are allowed to use (this seems like something you would want to prove straight from the axioms).

Comment: It IS something that I have to prove straight from the axioms...anyway my prof. didn't give me any conditions about what I can or cannot use..

Comment: What are the axioms you can use?

Comment: Sorry. Tried to give the link. Not working properly. You can re-insert the link or delete.

Answer (score 0):

You had to prove that *ray* $\overrightarrow{AD}$ intersects $\overline{BC}$; however, you proved only that *line* $\overleftrightarrow{AD}$ intersects $\overline{BC}$. The missing final steps are:

$13.$ $\overrightarrow{AG}$ and $\overline{BC}$, except for point $C$, lie on the opposite sides of $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$, so they have no points in common.

$14.$ That implies $\overrightarrow{AD}$ intersects $\overline{BC}$.

Also, there is a typo in step $5$: it should read $\overrightarrow{AD}$ instead of $\overleftrightarrow{AD}$.